# Space of symmetric matrices. Check idea

Tags: linear-algebra

> Prove that the space $S$ of the symmetric matrices $n \times n$ has dimension $n(n+1)/2$.

$\bf{Just\;an\;idea:}$

- Use induction
- For example: writte an arbitraty matrice $3 \times 3$ as

$\left(\begin{array}{ccc} a & b & c \\ b & d &e \\ c & e & f \end{array}\right) = a\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 &0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{array}\right) + b\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 &0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{array}\right) + c\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 &0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \end{array}\right) + d\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 &0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{array}\right) + e\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 &1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{array}\right) + f\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 &0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{array}\right)$.

- We obtain a set with $6 = 3(3 + 1)/2$ matrices LI, then a basis for space
- Use this fact in induction

This is just an idea. I want to know if it works.

Comment: Rather than using induction, I would suggest that you look at the patterns in the bases elements that you have written, which are correct. This will help you write down an explicit basis for the set of symmetric matrices for every dimension without requiring induction at all. In particular, all bases elements would have to have either a single one or two ones which are symmetric to each other : how many matrices have this property?

Answer (score 1):

$E_{i,j}+E_{j,i}$ are $\frac{n(n-1)}{2} + n$ symmetric linearly independent matrices (pick 2 different $i,j$ and $i=j$ in $n$ ways). $E_{i,j}-E_{j,i}$ are $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ antisymmetric linearly independent matrices (can't pick $i=j$ here). All of these are $n^2$ and of course all linearly independant cause $-A= A^T = A \implies A=0$.

Note that we are basically saying that the space of matrices can be splitted in symmetric + antisymmetric, and this sum is direct! (Remember that you can write every matrix $A = \frac{A+A^T}{2} + \frac{A-A^T}{2}$ where the first is of course symmetric and the second one antisymmetric. We also showed that a matrix can't be in the intersection of these 2 spaces cause a matrix can't be both symmetric and antisymmetric).